# Looking for help in jQuery ( buttons)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to use an HTML button to fade out ( after clicking on it) and have a table appear using jQuery... It's not been working great. Here is my HTML, CSS and Js.

```
 <br>
        <button id="boutton" ;
            <p id="boutton"> Meteo du Jour! </p>
        </button>
        <table id="tableau">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
```

my CSS

```
 #boutton {
    color: blue;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: #8b8b8b;
    text-align:center;
    margin:auto;
    border: 5px #2d2d2d solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#tableau {
    border: 8px solid #2d2d2d;
    width: 50%;
    height: 25%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}

table {
    border: 8px solid blue;
    width: 50%;
    height: 25%;
    border-spacing: 25px;
    background: #8b8b8b;
    border-radius: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

and this is my jQuery

```
$("#boutton").click(function(){
$("#tableau").css({"visibility":"visible"});
$("table").css({"visibility":"visible"});
$("#boutton").fadeOut(slow, linear);
```

Comment: Will you put all your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, please reduce your code to the absolute minium. No noise like background-color, border-radius et cetera.

Comment: You have an error on the 2nd line of your HTML code.

Comment: Also your jquery click function isn't being closed.

Comment: Also you're using `#boutton' twice, IDs should be single instances, and most of your HTML is being left unclosed.

Comment: I didn't close my HTML because it's minimised, my complete code does 59 lines of HTML, 58 of CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a jsFiddle for you

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/236er/)

There were some bugs in your jQuery (missing parentheses, brackets) so I fixed those and removed some things I found redundant

```
$("#boutton").click(function() {
$("#tableau").css({"visibility":"visible"});
$("#boutton").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Josh's solution you could use jQuery toggle to hide/show the table.

[jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

**JQUERY**

```
$("#boutton").click(function() {
    $("#tableau").toggle();
    $("#boutton").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

**CSS**

```
#tableau {  
    display: none;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D35Tk/)